# Finding the reduced permutations of six numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

I am trying to use *Mathematica* to find the following set of permutations:

$$\sum_{\rho\in \tilde{S}_{n+2}} {\rm sgn}(\rho)\eta^{\mu_{\rho_{(1)}}\mu_{\rho_{(2)}}}
$$
where 
$$
\tilde{S}_{n+2}:=\{\rho\in S_{n+2}: \rho_{(1)}<\rho_{(2)}\}
$$
is the the reduced set of all permutations of $n+2$ numbers, and ${\rm sgn}$ is the sign function. Now I want to have it for 6 numbers, to use mathematica to find the set of all reduced permutations of {1,2,3,4,5,6}. Probably I should use `DeleteCases`, but I do not know how to put the condition in the reduced permutation. Any ideas?

Comment: You're going to have to help us with the notation a bit. (1) You say "following set of permutations" when what I see is a *sum* over a set of permutations. (2) What is $\eta$? What is $\mu$? What is the notation $\rho_{(1))}$? (does it mean the permutation $\rho$ applied to element $1$)? What does $\mu_{\rho_{(1)}}$ mean? I actually want to help with this problem, because my gut reaction is that it could be interesting and fun to solve, but as it stands, I have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: Anyway. Maybe this: `reducedPerms = Cases[Permutations@Range[6], a_ /; a[[1]] < a[[2]]]`. And this: `signs = Signature /@ reducedPerms`. Or:  `reducedPerms = Select[Permutations@Range[6], #[[1]] < #[[2]]&.]`

Comment: Sorry, you are right it is a sum over all permutations...$\eta$ is simply the Kronecker delta, $\mu$ is an index for the member of the set...and $\rho{(1)}$ is the first member of each permutation set, let say for example $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ then $\rho_{(1)}=1$ etc

Comment: we can simply forget about the first equation, the second one is related to my question, if you have a sum over a set of permutations and you have to exclude some of them, in this case I just need those which the first member is smaller than the second one, and the other four could be anything..

Comment: What you just suggested seems to work march, thanks

Comment: @march. How about posting your comment as an answer to get this question off the unanswered question list? I will up-vote.

Comment: @m_goldberg. I'll post an answer when I get the chance. Should be within two hours or so.

Comment: I would like to solve the sum problem too, but I am still confused. In the "exponent" of the $\eta$, are you multiplying the $\mu$'s, or are those just two arguments for the function? Is $\mu$ the list `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`, or is it some other list which might have repeated elements (which I suspect)? Further, for the permutation `{4,1,2,3,5,6}`, is $\mu_{\rho(1)}=\mu_4=4$ or is it that `mu = {a, b, c, d, e, f}`, and so $\mu_{\rho(1)}=\mu_4=d$?

Comment: I think my question was too abstract, what I am looking for is to find a kind of general representation to antisymmetrize any  number of variables, I found this representation in a paper and a part of that representation was what I wrote above. The complete form is the following:

Comment: I think my question was too abstract, what I am looking for is to find a kind of general representation to antisymmetrize any  number of gamma matrices, I found this representation in a paper and a part of that representation was what I wrote above. The complete form is the following: $\gamma^{[\mu_1}\gamma^\mu_2\cdots\gamma^{\mu_{n+2}]}=\gamma^{\mu_1}\gamma^{\mu_2}\cdots\gamma^{\mu_{n+2}}+\sum_{\rho\in\tilde{S}_{n+2}}{\rm sgn}(\rho)\eta^{\mu_{\rho_{(1)}}\mu_{\rho_{(2)}}}n!\gamma^{[\mu_{\rho_{(3)}}... \mu_{\rho_{(n+2)}}]}$

Comment: where $\rho_{(1)},\rho_{(2)}\cdots$ are the first member, the second member etc of each set in the sum. And $\mu$ is a Lorentz index which in four spacetime dimension runs from $\{0,1,2,3\}$, and in the $\eta^{\mu_i\mu_j}$ simply means putting $\mu_i=\mu_j$, imagine you have $a_{\mu_1}b_{\mu_2}\eta^{\mu_1,\mu_2}=a_{\mu_1}b^{\mu_1}=a\cdot b$. I hope it make my mess clear and sorry guys...

Comment: But, what I need, is antisymmetrized form of for six gamma matrices, that is why I asked you guys how can I use mathematica for the reduced permutation of six variables.

Answer (score 4):

We start by generating all permutations and selecting those that satisfy the condition. There are two possibilities, one using `Select` and one using `Cases`. Take your pick.

```
n = 6;
reducedPerms = Cases[Permutations@Range[n], a_ /; a[[1]] < a[[2]]];
reducedPerms = Select[Permutations@Range[n], #[[1]] < #[[2]] &];
```

We can get the `Signature` of a permutation by using `Signature`:

```
Signature[{1,2,3,5,4,6}]
(* -1 *)
```

Comment: Another possibility: `Select[Permutations[Range[6]], OrderedQ[Take[#, 2]] &]`.